# doing a get is changing the value of the column

Tags: laravel

I'm getting several data and there is a column that is status. This column is the status of the data, it has 2 options which are 'approve' and 'waiting'. I need to translate this into Portuguese. Is there a way to do this directly during the consultation?

```
public function pdvs()
    {
        $forms = Form::query()->where('forms.distributor_id', '!=', 1)->join('vouchers', 'forms.id', 'vouchers.form_id')->select('forms.cnpj', 'forms.status', 'vouchers.code', 'vouchers.quantityLiterPurchased')->get();

        return response()->json(json_decode($forms));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the 'approve' and 'waiting' status values directly within your Laravel query using the CASE statement to create a custom column with translated values. Here's how you can modify your query to achieve this:

```
public function pdvs()
{
    $forms = Form::query()
        ->where('forms.distributor_id', '!=', 1)
        ->join('vouchers', 'forms.id', 'vouchers.form_id')
        ->select('forms.cnpj', \DB::raw('CASE WHEN forms.status = "approve" THEN "aprovado" ELSE "aguardando" END AS translated_status'), 'vouchers.code', 'vouchers.quantityLiterPurchased')
        ->get();

    return response()->json(json_decode($forms));
}
```